# Removing a "subset" from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, arraylist

I want to remove some elements from an array contained in another array.

The way to do this in Java is:

```
myArray.removeAll(anotherArray)
```

This code removes the elements contained in `anotherArray` from `myArray`.

Is there something like removing the elements contained in `myArray` INTERSECTION `anotherArray` from `myArray`?

Comment: Err, no, in Java, this will be `.removeAll()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is what [the `-` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-2D) (really `Array#-` method) is for:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [2]
a - b
# => [1]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, but I'm used to call methods like `-`, `+`, `[]` etc. "operators" - and it isn't incorrect, I guess?
EDIT: indeed, it might be misleading for beginners, so I added small explanation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree, that's why I edited my answer after your suggestion. And the link to the docs was included in my answer even before this edit.

Answer (score 0):

### Use "Array Difference"

There's more than one way to do this in Ruby, but the most common is to call the array difference method [`Array#-`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-2D). The documentation for this method says:

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any items that also appear in other_ary. The order is preserved from the original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.
>
> ```
> [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]
> ```
>
> If you need set-like behavior, see the library class Set.

The minus sign looks like an operator, but is actually a method call on the first Array object. Obviously, you could also look at [`Set#difference`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-difference) if you're working with Set objects rather than an Array.